Django cannot create a filed although I made makemigrations and migrate
I have a file I cannot make it in database although I made makemigrations and migrte this is models.py
     class Display(models.Model) :
      url=models.URLField(unique=True)
     text = models.CharField(max_length=150) 
    
    class  Display_Data(models.Model) :
         displays = models.ManyToManyField(Display,related_name='display_data')  
        users= models.ForeignKey(UserProfile,on_delete=models.CASCADE,default="1")
         choosenum=models.IntegerField()
         puplish_date =models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)  

and this is models.py for accounts app
  `class UserProfile(models.Model):
   user=models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   `user_nickname=models.CharField(max_length=150)
    `nikename_url=models.URLField()
   `userphoto =models.ImageField(upload_to='imageprofile/%Y/%m/%d/')

and this is views.py for display app
def check_url_exists_and_person(url_to_check):
   user_info_array = []

 for i in range(1, 6):
     latest_successful_record = Display_Data.objects.filter(displays__url=url_to_check,
     choosenum=i).order_by('-puplish_date').first()

      if latest_successful_record:
          user_info = {
             'user_nickname': latest_successful_record.users.userprofile.nikename,
             'url': latest_successful_record.users.userpofile.nikename_url
         }
    else:
        user_info = None

        user_info_array.append(user_info)

           return user_info_array

I received a mistake from Django
'Unknown column 'display_display_data.users_id' in 'field list'")
and this is form traceback
`D:\github\faithsearch\display\views.py, line 104, in display_video
Darry=check_url_exists_and_date(embed_url) …`

▶ Local vars
D:\github\faithsearch\display\views.py, line 68, in check_url_exists_and_date
latest_successful_record = Display_Data.objects.filter(displays__url=url_to_check, choosenum=i).order_by('-puplish_date').first()
Why does the database not have a filed user_id although I make it in models.py I made a new database and deleted files of migrations in application display and app userprofile and the filed is not created.

Please reformat the code properly. Remove the your text...

thank you i delete it

Can you also share the full traceback as well as the migration file?

i edit the question and add from traceback but i can not open migrations files to accounts app and there is not migrations files in display app

If you are early if you projects life cycle, don't have a prod db with data in
it and also don't care about the dev data inside the dev db, do:
1. Delete db.sqlite3.
2. Delete all migrations rm {myapp}/migrations/00*.
3. makemigrations.
4. migrate.
Aka: "chuck it!" it isn't worth the time to figure it out imo.

i  detete all migrathion files i work in mysql database i change the name of database in sitting.py to a new database i make makemigrations i recived "no changes" i make migrate they build all the essential database   admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions but they dont migrate for app display  ,accounts

thank you its done i makemigrations for display and accounts and them make migrate and field was created thank you
